# Data.Tree for Fay

Tags: haskell, fay

I am using `Data.Tree.unfoldTree` in a Fay script but it cannot be compiled and it is not included in fay-base. Is there a way to import from `Data.Tree`?

Comment: Fay is a very small subset of Haskell; if you want more, check out GHCJS or Haste.